# Castear una lista a otra lista de objetos

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Tengo un dataTable que contiene 4 columnas. Luego, tengo una consulta a fileTable que lo hago con `EntityFramework` que devuelve otra lista.

Por ultimo, necesito hacer un `InnerJoin` entre esas dos listas.

<sub>Aclaracion: he logrado hacerlo con un bucle, pero demora mucho tiempo. (Que opciones tengo?)</sub>

```vb
For Each d As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
    Dim s As String = d.Item("codigo")
    If db.TieneProgramaUnaMAteria(s, d.Item(4)) Then
        d.Item("Tiene Programa") = "SI"
    Else
        d.Item("Tiene Programa") = "NO"
    End If
Next
```

Mi idea es crear un objeto, con la misma cantidad de propiedades que columnas tiene le DataTable, y luego llenar una lista creando un objeto por cada fila del dataTable.

Algo asi (es un pseudo codigo):

```vb
Dim listaProgramasBD = db.ProgramaFileTable_VSet.Any(Function(x) x.unc_path.Contains("\programas_ft\programasSubidosWeb\") andalso                                                  x.is_archive)

  Dim listaDT As List(Of ProgramasLivianos) = dataTable.AsEnumerable.ToList()'<--- esta linea es la que no estoy sabiendo realizar.

    Dim resultado = From l In listaProgramasBD , p In listaDT
                    Where l.name.Contains(p.codSiu)
                    Select p
```

En definitiva, mi pregunta es como hacer la siguiente linea de una manera eficiente

```vb
Dim listaDT As List(Of ProgramasLivianos) = dataTable.AsEnumerable.ToList()
```

Saludos

Editado:
 He hecho un bucle que resolveria esa cuestion, para poder seguir adelante con el sistema, pero me gustaría saber si hay una manera mas eficiente de hacerlo, pego el bucle para que tengan una idea mas acabada de lo que necesito

```vb
Dim lista As New List(Of ProgramasLivianos)
Dim p As New ProgramasLivianos
For Each r As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
    p.codSiu = r.Item(0)
    p.MateriaDelSiuID = r.Item(1)
    p.nombre = r.Item(2)
    p.nombre_Reducido = r.Item(3)
    p.plan = r.Item(4)
Next
Return lista
```

Comment: Me temo que lo que quieres no es posible hacerlo usando linq, Al final, tienes que "mapear" los datos de cada `DataRow` a tu clase. Para cosas como estas puedes usar alguna herramienta tipo [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)